# Which kind of events happned on AWS Elastic Beanstalkwill trigger SNS notification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS EBS application and I managed to attach an SNS service to it. However, only some of the events are sent to SNS. I check the docs, it says all notable events including "environment creation errors and all changes in environment and instance health." will trigger the SNS. But kind of events are defined as environment creation errors? Is there a list?

Comment: Note that EBS is not the abbreviation for Elastic Beanstalk.   EBS is Elastic Block Store.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found a list of environment creation errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/troubleshooting-envcreate.html). It does seem a bit ambiguous in general that it's only "notable" events, since how does one really define "notable", it could be different for everyone. But theoretically you will never miss anything important happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got one more question. Are the events defined by EBS arbitrarily or they could be defined by us through health reporting?

Comment: From my understanding they are defined by EBS